# Autocorrelation in DOLS: will HAC standard errors work?

Tags: least-squares, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, cointegration, hac

I am currently estimating a cointegrating regression (DOLS), where my residuals have autocorrelation. Sometimes it is just in one or two lags, but sometimes it is more. My question is: Can I apply HAC and carry on with my estimation? I.e. would HAC standard errors compensate for the autocorrelation?

Comment: I edited the title in the hope of making it more informative. I hope I did not misrepresent your point. It is an interesting question, but looks like a tough one, too...

Comment: In DOLS, leads and lags compensate for autocorrelation. Why would you want to use HAC s.e.s on top?

Comment: Richard Hardy, thanks!

@ChristophHanck, because I have tried every possible combination of leads and lags and some autocorrelation still remains.

Answer (score 1):

The motivation for including leads/lags within a DOLS is to control for bias in small samples.  Actually, to be more specific the lags\leads are included to ensure that the OLS estimates are normally distributed.  More importantly, lag/leads are not related to correcting for autocorrelation.   These issue are first discussed in Banerjee 1986 et al, who shows that bias in introduced as a results of the strict exogeneity assumption not holding. Saikkonen 1991 is the first to suggest using lag/lead difference to control for bias.

More importantly for your application is that it is actually essential you use HAC variance.  As a matter of fact the seminal paper on DOLS, Stock and Watson (1993), discusses this in-depth. Read these [Zivot Notes](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/cointegration.pdf), since they contain the essential information.  For a application with Newey-West errors read [this](http://down.cenet.org.cn/upfile/54/200842021150161.pdf).